# Resolve issue in jira by using rest api

Tags: node.js, rest, post, jira, jira-rest-api

Can I resolve the issue in JIRA?
I made some trials with REST API as;

```
var url = "https://hibernate.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/WEBSITE-1/transitions";
var message = [{
    "update": {
        "comment": [
            {
                "add": {
                    "body": "some text for body"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "fields": {
        "assignee": {
            "name": "name1"
        },
        "resolution": {
            "name": "Fix"
        }
    },
    "transition": {
        "id": "1"
    }
}];
request({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    body: message,
}, function (error){});
```

Url(https://hibernate.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/WEBSITE-1/transitions) gives me;

```
{"expand":"transitions","transitions":[]}
```

How can I resolve an issue in JIRA? Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You've got the right approach, but you need to authenticate your requests with a user that has permission to execute the transition.

Because you execute your requests anonymously, JIRA gives you a response that does not contain any transitions you can execute and will not allow you to perform a transition.

Take a look at the documentation for the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication) or another [example](https://dzone.com/articles/nodejs-call-https-basic).

Answer (score -1):

To get the full list of transitions, append the string `?expand=transitions.fields` to your existing url. So in this case it would look like

```
var url = "https://hibernate.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/WEBSITE-1/transitions?expand=transitions.fields";
```